Trying to filter a sql report by a range of numbers
I have this SQL code that runs product sales information, however I would like it to display a set range of numbers.  The ALU is my product numbers, I have a large range of numbers and would only like to see ALU numbers between 4000000 and 4009999.  Here is my current code.  I have selected some results to be ignored.
Any help in the right direction would be great.
select 
       --r.sbs_name as "Subsidiary",
       r.store_code as "Store",
       r.ALU as "ALU",
       --r.dcs_code as "DCS Code",
       --r.vend_code as "Vendor Code",
       r.description1 as "Description1",
       --r.attribute as "Attribute",
       --r.item_size as "Size",
       r.qty_sold as "Qty Sold",
       round(
            case when r.ext_cost = 0
                then 0
                else (r.ext_cost / r.qty_sold)
            end, 2) as "Item Cost",
       r.ext_cost as "Total Cost",
       r.ext_price as "Total Retail"
from
(
    select s.sbs_name,
           St.Store_code,
           d.dcs_code,
           v.vend_code,
           i.description1,
           i.attribute,
           i.item_size,
           i.ALU,
           sum(decode(di.item_type, 2, di.qty * -1, di.qty)) as qty_sold,
           sum(round((decode(di.item_type, 2, di.qty * -1, di.qty) * (di.cost)), 2)) as ext_cost,
           sum(round((decode(di.item_type, 2, di.qty * -1, di.qty) * (di.price)), 2)) as ext_price
      from rps.document do
     inner join rps.document_item di
        on do.sid = di.doc_sid
     inner join rps.subsidiary s
        on do.sbs_no = s.sbs_no
       and di.sbs_no = s.sbs_no
     inner join rps.dcs d
        on s.sid = d.sbs_sid
       and di.dcs_code = d.dcs_code
     inner join rps.store st
        on do.store_sid = st.sid
     inner join rps.invn_sbs_item i
        on di.invn_sbs_item_sid = i.sid
       and s.sid = i.sbs_sid
     inner join rps.vendor v
        on i.vend_sid = v.sid
     where do.receipt_type in (0, 1)
       and di.item_type in (1, 2)
       and do.status = 4
       and =-=do.sbs_no=-=
       and =-=st.store_no=-=
       and =-=st.store_code=-=
       and =-=trunc(do.created_datetime)=-=
    group by s.sbs_name,
           St.Store_code,
           d.dcs_code,
           v.vend_code,
           i.description1,
           i.attribute,
           i.item_size,
           i.ALU
) r     

Tried adding between 4000000 and 4009999 but not sure of the correct command or location

Either of these should work:
    select 
           <your select clause>
    from
    (
        select <your select clause>
               sum(..)
          from <your from clause>
         where <your where clause)
            AND i.ALU between 4000000 and 4009999
        group by <your group by clause>
    ) r     

or

    select 
           <your select clause>
    from
    (
        select <your select clause>
               sum(..)
          from <your from clause>
         where <your where clause)
        group by <your group by clause>
    ) r     
    where r.ALU between 4000000 and 4009999

Because your 'i' table (rps.invn_sbs_item) is inner joined to everything else, you can also add this condition to the ON cluse of the JOIN, if you wish.

The code errored out at first, then after further research I discovered not all products are using numeric as the alu.  I had to add ' in front and behind the number range. Ex. '4000000' and '4009999' after this I was able to get the required results.
